# How can I run JavaScript in Notepad++ without using HTML?

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I'd like to run Javascript Code in Notepad++ without HTML.
I already tried to use NppExec (plugin) but it didn't work.
Is there another plugin that i can use?

Example Code:

```
var A = 1
var B = 2
var C = A + B

alert(C);
```

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the syntax is valid in JavaScript. However it is seen as a good practice to end all your statement with semicolons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run JavaScript you need a runtime environment. This is generally provided by your browser.

You can use [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/), to run javascript without browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- You forgot to add **`;`** in the end of statements.
- As JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled language. So, you can put your JavaScript code inside `<script>` & `</script>` tag and `Run/Open` it in the browser.

  ```
  <script> 
      var A = 1
      var B = 2
      var C = A + B

      alert(C); // 3
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put ; in it

You need a runtime environment to run it but it should be provided by your browser

Answer (score 0):

cscript.exe filename.js

runs JS locally on a Windows with access to things like

```
FileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```